# Team member overwrite git changes

Tags: git, github, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Me and a friend are working on a small project hosted on Github. Neither of us are very experienced (clearly).

I submitted a pull request that was successfully merged however, my friend did not update his local repository to include these latest changes.

When my friend next did a `push`, he *overwrote* all of my changes.

How can I retain most (excluding conflicts) of my edits and his?

I tried making a branch based on my last commit, and then merging said branch with the master branch however doing so did not work because because the master branch was said to be "up to date"  and now I am lost.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit

Comment: The only way to overwrite data when pushing is using `--force`. If there's any problem while pushing, NEVER resort to that parameter, unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @Jim If I revert to my last commit all of his code will be lost no? How should I proceed after returning to my commit? Thanks.

Comment: @KurzedMetal Thanks for the advice Kurzed. I think my friend just searched around until he found a command that "worked". We are mostly working on this project to get experience with working as a team using Git.

Comment: @CasterTroy He should have his code locally still? If you revert and  he should be able to pull and merge with his current files... I think, I haven't used git in a while, but if he has his code locally, worst case scenario revert, get him to back his up and pull and go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to resolve this issue would be to do a `fetch` followed by a `merge` or a `rebase`. I would suggest a `rebase` to keep your history linear and clean.

`fetch` updates your copy of the remote branch while not touching your own branch. A `git pull` will effectively do a `fetch` followed by a `merge`.

The command chain to resolve your problem would look like this

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master master
# ... Solve conflicts ... (continue the rebase with 'git rebase --continue')
git push
```

If your friend commited during the time you were resolving the conflicts you should do a `git pull --rebase` before pushing. But git will tell you about this, when you try to `push`, so I wouldn't worry about it until it screams at you.